# How to get child categories using object manager?

Tags: magento2, object-manager, sub-categories

For now I'm getting category name.

This is my code:

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/storecategories.phtml

```
<?php
        $categoryId = 65;
        $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $category = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')
            ->load($categoryId);
        $parent = $category->getName();
        echo $parent?>
```

What would be next steps to get current categories subcategories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); // Instance of Object Manager
 $categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');// Instance of Category Model
 $categoryId = 15; // YOUR CATEGORY ID
 $category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
 // Children  Categories
 $childrenCategories = $category->getChildrenCategories();
```

Comment: When I try to echo $category->getChildrenCategories();
I got this error:

Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Category\Collection could not be converted to string

Maybe you know the solution?

Comment: $ChildrenCategories is in form of array try printing it by print_r(childrenCategories)

Comment: I intend to put it into foreach loop and display it in <ul> <li>.
I suppose it's not possible with print_r.
Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: try using for each loop
foreach($childrenCategories as $childSubcategorie) {
            echo '        --> '.$childSubcategorie->getName().'<br/>';
        }

Comment: Thank's a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following?

```
 $category->getChildrenCategories();
```