# Get category name by ID

Tags: magento2, category, dependency-injection

This is my Vendor/Module/Block/BlockFile.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class CategoryList extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

   public function getId()
  {
    return $this->getData('category_id');
  }

}
```

For now I'm getting category ID.

I need to get category name by ID using dependency injection.

Comment: already asked on the same type of  questions on your different Question

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/262467/4564 .See , you already  posted the same type of question.On your question, you already have given the answer

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
class CategoryList extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * CategoryList constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
    ) {
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     * @param null $storeId
     * @return string
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    protected function getCategoryNameById($id, $storeId = null)
    {
        $categoryInstance = $this->categoryRepository->get($id, $storeId);

        return $categoryInstance->getName();
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->getData('category_id');
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCategoryName()
    {
        try {
            return $this->getCategoryNameById($this->getId());
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException $exception) {
            return 'Unknown Category';
        } 
    }
}
```